# IONIC:Unable to install phonegap-plugin-push in ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am new with ionic framework.Currently i am working on ionic iOS app. when i install `phonegap-plugin-push`    i am getting error

```
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push':undefined  Error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

i have searched it but no solution found yet!

Answer (score 1):

I also got same kind of problem. In my case I used `sudo ionic platform add ios`

This is worked well while building every plugins but phonegap-plugin-push.

phonegap-plugin-push is keep giving above error `[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)`

Then I used `ionic platform add ios` without `sudo` This is the actual solution for this. But in this case It is keep giving me the permission related issue `code EACCESS`.

Then I used followings step to overcome that one.

- `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/`
- Again added cordoava and ionic
- `sudo npm install -g cordova`
- `sudo npm install -g ionic`

**Other informations**

- phonegap-plugin-push version: 1.10.0
- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
- Node Version: v7.7.2
- Xocde Version: Xcode 8.2.1
- CocoaPods Version: 1.2.0

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much @stack fan for the answer.sorry for late reply actually i  switched to `Firebase`  for notification.

Comment: @Nupur Jain np :). Just try it above way if one day you are going work with phonegap-plugin-push