# Failed to install 'aerogear-cordova-push':undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, aerogear

While `sudo ionic platform add ios` i'm getting below error,
I added 'aerogear-cordova-push' plugin after that removed platforms and trying to add again.

```
Failed to install 'aerogear-cordova-push':undefined

Error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)



Cordova CLI: 7.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.44
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Any Advice?

I Tried [IONIC:Unable to install phonegap-plugin-push in ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665360/ionicunable-to-install-phonegap-plugin-push-in-ios-app) but didnot help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sudo on your cordova/ionic/phonegap commands. If you have npm permission problems, consider using nvm (node version manager).

When you install the plugin, a `pod install` command is run by Cordova, and `pod install` can be run when using sudo. (The error "You cannot run CocoaPods as root." message is telling you that)